# Удалить из Excel файла строки, не содержащие подстроку

Tags: c#, excel

```
using System;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

namespace ExelEditor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\root\3.xlsx";
                var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);

                foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows())
                {
                    string targetCell = row.Cell(5).GetString();
                    if (targetCell.Contains("Заречная") == false && targetCell.Contains("Адрес регистрации") == false)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(targetCell);
                        //Console.ReadKey();
                        row.Delete();
                    }
                }
                workbook.Save();
                Console.WriteLine("Успешно!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка! Введен неверный путь до exel-файла.");
                Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка: " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Второй вариант

```
using System;
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ExelEditor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\root\3.xlsx";
                var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);
                var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Новый лист");
                for (int i = worksheet.RowsUsed().Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var row = worksheet.Row(i);
                    string targetCell = row.Cell(5).GetString();
                    if (targetCell.Contains("Заречная") == false && targetCell.Contains("Адрес регистрации") == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(targetCell);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        row.Delete();
                    }
                }

                workbook.Save();
                Console.WriteLine("Успешно!");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка! Введен неверный путь до exel-файла.");
                Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка: " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку out of memory

Comment: так код есть, вопрос то где? что не получается

Comment: Процесс добирается до строки row.Delete(); зависает и программа прекращает выполнение, причём без ошибок

Comment: Возможно проблема в том что я изменяю коллекцию во время итерации по ней?

Comment: да изменение коллекции во время итерации может быть не самым лучшим вариантом. я бы наверно сначала получил коллекцию строк подлежащих удаление а потом их удалил

Comment: Не совсем понятно как это сделать...

Comment: например создаете список в который будете добавлять только те строки которые необходимо удалить: `HashSet<int> forDeleting = new HashSet<int>();` в цикле в котором обходите все строки таблицы в условии проверки строки добавляете в этот список индексы строк, затем обходите список `forDeleting` и удаляете строки